# Determine building name from CLGeocoder

Tags: ios12, clgeocoder

Is it possible to determine the building (or another landmark) your in with `CLGeocoder` or any other Apple location service SDK?

I can see the address of my current location using long & lat using `CLGeocoder`.  However, I would also like to return the building I'm in.  For example, if I'm in the Rogers Centre in Toronto, I'd like to have that returned based on my current location.

Thanks

Comment: You're talking to a database. You cannot retrieve info that isn't in the database.

Comment: The reason I ask is because it’s in Apple Maps…

Comment: Understood, but that is not the same as the geocoding database.